# Integrate $\frac{\sqrt {x} }{\sqrt{2x +3}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

My attempt to the solution:
Substitute $u:=\sqrt{x}$. Then $x= u^2$  and differentiating we get $2u \ du= dx $

$\int \frac{2u^2}{\sqrt{2u^2+3}}du=\int \frac{2u^2+3-3}{\sqrt{2u^2+3}}du=\int \frac{2u^2+3}{\sqrt{2u^+3}}du-\int\frac{3}{\sqrt{2u^2+3}}du$

Comment: Please use mathjax.

Comment: This is difficult to read. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you mean $$\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{2x+3}}dx$$?

Answer (score 1):

Please take some time to properly typeset your question, there's a [manual](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to use MathJax.

I'm assuming you want to find:

> $$\int\sqrt{\frac{x}{2x+3}} \,\mbox{d}x$$

**Hint**

$$t^2 = \frac{x}{2x+3} \implies x = \frac{3t^2}{1-2t^2}$$

From here, you find $\mbox{d}x = \ldots \mbox{d}t$ and you get a rational function to integrate.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Rather try to make the denominator free of radical sign by substituting,

> $$2x+3 = u^2$$

$$x = \frac{u^2-3}{2}$$

$$dx= udu$$

> $$I = \int\sqrt{\frac{u^2-3}{2u^2}}udu = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int\sqrt{u^2-3} \ du$$

which can be evaluated by using the identity $\color{blue}{\int\sqrt{u^2-a^2}du = \frac{u}{2}\sqrt{u^2-a^2}-\frac{a^2}{2}\ln|u+\sqrt{u^2-a^2}|+c}$

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome :)